# What manner of regular expression might I use to add line breaks near HTML tags?

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have the following regular expression which is used to give me the tags in the HTML string:

```
<[^>]*>
```

So, if I pass in the following:

```
<b> Bold </b>
```

Then it will give me:

```
<b>
</b>
```

How can I make it to give me:

```
<b>
Bold
</b>
```

UPDATE:

Here is another example to get the big picture:

If this is the text:

```
<b>Bold</b> This is the stuff <i>Italic</i>
```

then the final result would be the following:

```
matches[0] = <b>
matches[1] = Bold
matches[2] = </b>
matches[3] = This is the stuff
matches[4] = <i>
matches[5] = Italic 
matches[6] = </i>
```

Comment: The answer is not to use regexes to parse HTML.

Comment: What language are you doing this in?  I could point you to some HTML parsers for whichever language you are calling this regex from.

Comment: I am using c# language and currently looking at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/TagBasedHtmlParser.aspx

Comment: @azamsharp: I'd recommend the HTML Agility Pack for something like this: http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack

Comment: @Luke, HtmlAgilityPack might be very complicated for a simple task that I need to perform.

Comment: @azamsharp: Maybe you should tell us specifically what task you need to do and why so that we can come up with the best way to do it.

Comment: Basically, I just need to pass in a string to a function and get the matches or an array of elements. Each element will be a tag or the content between the tag. Please refer to the above example!

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to write your own HTML parser to me. Unless it's homework or you're learning to write parsers, don't. There are dozens of parsers available that will do the work for you.

Comment: The downvoters should be ashamed. There's nothing wrong with the question itself.

Comment: @Imran: uh... I didn't downvote this, but i'm surprised to see you chastising whoever did - i'd think the reason would be obvious, given the comments so far (azamsharp's asking for help with a sub-optimal technique, rather than explaining his task so that a better technique might be suggested).

Comment: @Shog9, I have explained the question in detail even giving two examples. Anyway, no problems!

Comment: I did not knew that it will be so complicated when using a Regex expression!

Comment: @Shog9: The only difference I see between http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456815/problems-with-html-marquee-tag and this question is the former got mentioned in SO podcast.

Comment: Uh... they're completely different questions. Down-voting doesn't have to mean "inappropriate" or even "poor" - it can just mean "beware!" :shrug: No worries - everyone has their own reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second the advice not to use reglar expressions; html can't be properly expressed using a regular language.

Better to investigate System.Xml.XmlReader and System.Web.HtmlWriter. You should be able to write a function that reads an element from a reader then writes it to a writer; something along the lines of

```
    public static string HtmlReformat(string html)
    {
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(html));

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            switch (rdr.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    htmlWriter.WriteEndTag(rdr.Name);
                    htmlWriter.Write(System.Environment.NewLine);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        htmlWriter.WriteBeginTag(rdr.Name);
                        for (int attributeIdx = 0; attributeIdx < rdr.AttributeCount; attributeIdx++)
                        {
                                string attribName = rdr.GetAttribute(attributeIdx);
                                htmlWriter.WriteAttribute(rdr.Name, attribName);
                        }
                        htmlWriter.Write(">");
                        htmlWriter.Write(System.Environment.NewLine);
                        break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    htmlWriter.Write(rdr.Value);
                    break; 
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Handle " + rdr.NodeType);
            }

        }
        return sw.ToString();
    }
```

This should give you a base to work from, anyway.

Answer (score 11):

**Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML.** [HTML is not regular](http://welbog.homeip.net/glue/53/XML-is-not-regular), and therefore regex is not at all suited to parsing it. Use an HTML or XML parser instead. There are many (HT|X)ML parsers available online. What language are you using?

You're not going to be able to create a regular expression that matches HTML because of the complexity of the language. Regex operates on a class of languages smaller than the class HTML is a member of. Any regex you try to write will be hard to understand and incorrect.

Use something like XPath instead.

EDIT: You're using C#. Luckily you have an entire [System.Xml namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml(VS.71).aspx) available to you. Also, there are other libraries for parsing HTML specifically if your HTML is not strict.

Comment: @azamsharp: If you're using C# then check out the HTML Agility Pack: http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack

Answer (score 2):

If the input is XHTML, then it's also legal XML, so you can do all this with some simple XSLT.

Answer (score -1):

If what you are using to regular expressions supports backward references you can use `<(.*?)>.*?</\1>`. This works in perl.

Comment: Really don't understand these vote downs - the question was "how do I change the regex I have to do something else". I understand from an implementation view point that regular expressions are not the way to parse HTML, but one many occasions learning is about demonstration of ideas outside of a realistic context. I answered the question - just don't vote it up.

Answer (score -2):

Html Tags are some of the biggest pains for Regex. You have to be careful because simply matching first and last tag won't be enough if you have more than one tag on the same line, or depending on how you evaluate it, anywhere in the string you're evaluating.

Here is a decent expression you can use...

```
@"<(?<tag>\w*)>(?<text>.*)</\k<tag>>"
```

You will have named groups *tag* and *text* that you can use to access the values you have. With those values you can format your. Depending on your language, you may need to specify that you want to search the entire string as a single line.

Comment: The above expression only gave one big search result which was the complete string passed to it.

Comment: Ah, well your example showed a single tag. That changes what the answer would have been.